# Convert from gray to BGR

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision

I want to convert my grey mnist to color. I have came up with the following code, but the output is still gray.

```
# Import
(train_images0, train_labels0), (test_images, test_labels) = tensorflow.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

# Split
train_images, val_images, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(train_images0, train_labels0, test_size=0.20)

#Convert to color BGR
output = cv2.cvtColor(train_images[88],cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

#Show before and after
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(train_images[88],cmap='gray')
```

[image: Before and after]

Can comeone point me in the right direction?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this tutorial to colour the image?

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/25/black-and-white-image-colorization-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/#download-the-code

You need to train your model first and then you can convert the image to colour using cv2

````
    # load the input image from disk, scale the pixel intensities to the
# range [0, 1], and then convert the image from the BGR to Lab color
# space
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
scaled = image.astype("float32") / 255.0
lab = cv2.cvtColor(scaled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)```
````